# Is there a standard notation for the set of roots of a polynomial?

Tags: soft-question, notation

For something so pervasive in mathematics, I'm surprised this doesn't have a simple and convenient notation. I suppose one could just always write $p^{-1}(0)$ but that somehow feels strange.

Comment: Quick answer: no, there isn't.

Comment: I mean, you could write something like $\operatorname{ker} p$, similar to how the set of vectors taken to zero by a linear transformation $T$ is denoted $\operatorname{ker}T$. But this can risk confusion since $p$ is of course not linear, so its set of zeroes isn't a vector space unlike the linear algebra case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In algebraic geometry, a [*variety*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_variety) is defined to be the solution set of a system of polynomials over an algebraically closed field. More precisely, if $k$ is an algebraically closed field and $f_1,\dots,f_m$ are polynomials in $n$ variables with coefficients in $k$, then 
$$V(f_1,\dots,f_n) = \{(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in k^n \mid f_1(x_1,\dots x_n)=\cdots = f_m(x_1,\dots, x_n) = 0\}.$$
However, this does not necessarily coincide with what you are looking for, since I assume your $p$ is a map $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed. You could, however, write $V(p)$ to describe the set of solutions of $p$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: There exists something called "real algebraic geometry".